# Finder view like FTP clients - two columns

Tags: finder, macos

Is here possible to have OS X (10.10) view like in FTP clients (e.g FileZilla) I mean two columns with list view, and of course without need of opening two seperate windows. I am aware of tabs, but can one show to tabs at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No dual mode in OS X Finder

There is no native dual mode in OS X Finder. You can replace Finder with software like '[TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com)' (image below). Or you can use window managing software, like [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) or [mjolnir](https://github.com/sdegutis/mjolnir), to place your Finder windows side-by-side.

[Mjolnir](https://github.com/sdegutis/mjolnir) (donation ware) is highly scriptable and should be capable of doing exactly this.

This feature is requested lots of times, but for now we are stuck with the classic Finder as we know it. Besides tabs, the only view options we have are:

- <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> - icons
- <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> - list
- <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> - columns
- <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> - Cover Flow

*TotalFinder, dual mode:*

[image: dualmode totalfinder]

Answer (score -1):

Command + T creates two tabs that you can toggle between.

Comment: Does your answer pertain to OS X 10.10, as the OP asked and what this queustion is about, or to the most recent version of macOS?  It's my understanding the this can't be done in 10.10.